# How can I make a div vertically responsive according to display

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a div vertically responsive just like `<img src="img.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;">`, so that the image does not lose its shape in any condition and height changes according to the re-sizing browser.. similarly if i make a slider div with `width 100%` and initially `max-height 600px`. So I want it's to reduce height like it's width. If I use `vh` method then it does not give good result in mobile view. A good example of a working slider is on the following link.

[example slider.](http://demo.webeasy.cf/likeschannel/)

Comment: Do you intend to have the div maintaining aspect ratio based on its content or background image?

Comment: I think,,...,,.........    you are right..

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Answer (score 0):

use css instead of `<img />`

```
.image{
   background-image    : url(<image_url>);
   background-size     : cover;
   background-position : center;
   background-repeat   : no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: inspecting the element in the "working slider" that you gave, is showing the exact solution that I wrote...